# GAE data store not returning entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have used objectify to query the GAE datastore i have set up that has at least one entity in it but i keep getting the following response

```
200 OK
```

- Show headers -

{

"kind": "call#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"AiR-q6YO1YYMgAaz-ZfT_fl7oeY/pcKQAVaDylr_ZSckRfQAxsphOUU\""

}

here is what the objectify request looks like

```
@ApiMethod(name = "queryCalls", path = "queryCalls", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)

public List<Call> queryCalls()
{
    Query<Call> query = ofy().load().type(Call.class).order("name");
    return query.list();


}
```

Call is obviously the class of the entity that is being used.

Any solutions would be most appreciated

EDIT
Here is the call class for reference

```
package com.cms.log;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;



/* Patient Entity */
@Entity
public class Call {

@Id Long callId;
@Index String patientName;
@Index String doctor;
String address1;
String address2;
String address3;
String postCode;
String patientLocation;
@Index String symptoms;
Integer contactNumber;
@Index String callDateTime;
String currentStatus;



 public Call(Long callId, String patientName, String doctor, String address1,
        String address2, String address3, String postCode, String patientLocation, String symptoms,
        Integer contactNumber, String callDateTime, String currentStatus) 
{
    this.callId = callId;
    this.patientName = patientName;
    this.doctor = doctor;
    this.address1 = address1;
    this.address2 = address2;
    this.address3 = address3;
    this.postCode = postCode;
    this.patientLocation = patientLocation;
    this.symptoms = symptoms;
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    this.callDateTime = callDateTime;
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
};

public Long getCallId() {
    return callId;
}

public void setCallId(Long Id) {
    this.callId = Id;
}

public String getPatientName() {
    return patientName;
}

public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
    this.patientName = patientName;
}

public String getDoctor() {
    return doctor;
}

public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
    this.doctor = doctor;
}

public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}

public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}

public String getAddress3() {
    return address3;
}

public void setAddress3(String address3) {
    this.address3 = address3;
}

public String getPostCode() {
    return postCode;
}

public void setPostCode(String postCode) {
    this.postCode = postCode;
}

public String getPatientLocation() {
    return patientLocation;
}

public void setPatientLocation(String patientLocation) {
    this.patientLocation = patientLocation;
}

public String getSymptoms() {
    return symptoms;
}

public void setSymptoms(String symptoms) {
    this.symptoms = symptoms;
}

public int getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}

public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}

public String getCallDateTime() {
    return callDateTime;
}

public void setCallDateTime(String callDateTime) {
    this.callDateTime = callDateTime;
}

public String getCurrentStatus() {
    return currentStatus;
}

public void setCurrentStatus(String currentStatus) {
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
}
```

}

Comment: So, are you saying you're getting no results back from your query?  You'll need to include relevant parts of your `Call` class to help others understand the problem.

Comment: yes thats what i am saying and i will include the call class in an edit now

Comment: I can't see a `name` property in your `Call` class. Do you mean `patientName`?

Comment: i tried adding in patientName and it gave me a 503 error

Comment: You'll need to look at your web application logs in the developer console to see what is causing the error.

Comment: it keeps giving me an error with Umbrella exception. This seems to be a java error that requires an exception to be added but im not sure on how to apply this to my API method. This never happened with the save method so i am confused as to how it is happening with this query method

Comment: Ok so i looked back at the logs and it gave me this error
Caused by: com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading Call(5726607939469312): com.cms.log.Call must have a no-arg constructor
so i removed the order by and it still doesn't seem to respond corrctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have highlighted in your last comment, your `@Entity` classes must have a no-arg constructor in order for Objectify to be able to construct objects from Datastore entities.

Once that is sorted you will be able to order your results using `@Index`ed properties defined in your class.

Comment: how do i then re-create the constructor for the Call class without adding the arg constructor then????

Comment: You can have more than one constructor but the no-arg one is required.

Comment: That is super mate. Thank you so much. I had been working on this over the weekend and couldn't find an answer anywhere so thanks a million